# Random item from PHP array = "access array offset"

Tags: php, arrays, random

Im trying to get a single random key => value from an array but im getting the following error. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
$colors = array("Yellow Sun" => "FAE500", "Golden" => "fab600", "Orange Juice" => "FF6D00", "Photo Blue" => "A2E5F4");


$shuffled = shuffle($colors);
print_r($shuffled[0]);
```

> "Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in"

Comment: You don't have an index of 0. The color names are your indexes.

Comment: Also `shuffle()` returns `true` or `false`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 2):

`shuffle()` returns a boolean value indicating whether the shuffle was successful or not. Therefore, $shuffled is a boolean value and not an array. You can use the `array_rand()` function which returns a random key from an array.

```
<?php

$keys = array_keys($colors);
$random_key = $keys[array_rand($keys)];
echo $colors[$random_key];
```

Comment: that worked! TY - however I need to access the ket value pair?

Comment: this appears to only give the value. I need both. Any ideas :)

Comment: @Chris The key in this example is `$random_key`…!

Comment: TY I just can't seem to get the key, only the value shows up. I'll keep at it